# ListView setOnItemClickListener and setOnItemSelectedListener to store the Selected Item Index

Tags: android, android-2.2-froyo

I have read on this site that it is necessary to customize the setOnItemSelectedListener and setOnItemClickListener of a ListView if we want to know the Index of the SelectedItem (.getSelectedItemPosition()). So that is what I do but it does not stores the position of the SekectedItem, instead i have always -1...

What I want to do is just to give the user a way to delete items from a list by selected and Item and Clicking a button.

See the code below :

```
    listViewPeople.setOnItemClickListener(new ListView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v, int i, long l) {
            try {
                // Remembers the selected Index
                listViewPeopleId = listViewPeople.getSelectedItemPosition();
            }
            catch(Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Nay, cannot get the selected index");
            }
        }
    });

    listViewPeople.setOnItemSelectedListener(new ListView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> a, View v, int i, long l) {
            try {
                // Remembers the selected Index
                listViewPeopleId = listViewPeople.getSelectedItemPosition();
                System.out.println("Yay, set the selected index " + listViewPeopleId);
            }
            catch(Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Nay, cannot get the selected index " + listViewPeopleId);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
            try {
                // Remembers nothing selected
                listViewPeopleId = -1;
                System.out.println("Yay, set that nothing is selected " + listViewPeopleId);
            }
            catch(Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Nay, cannot set that nothing is selected " + listViewPeopleId);
            }
        }
    });
```

What's wrong??

Thank you for your help!

Christophe

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Instead of doing `listViewPeople.getSelectedItemPosition();` try using the int i parameter to get the index.

Comment: great ! just had to change the remove method as well to :

 arrayPeople.remove(arrayPeople.get(listViewPeopleId));