# android listview with checkbox

Tags: android, listview, checkbox

I have a listview with each row having a checkbox, imageview and text view

my requirements are 
1. checkbox can be checkd and unchecked and for each click on checkbox for each row do function1 : This i could do by defining an onitem clicklistenr for the check box within the getview of the baseadapter

1. If any other item than check box is clicked i want to interpret this as a row click and do function 2. Currently i defined an onitemclick listener for the textview and it works

So my question is is that the right way to do it, define onitemclick listener for all other items and make it call function 2 ?

Or is there a way i can achieve the row selection for my list.
Please see my code below . I can give any further details if needed

list.java

```
public class ScanListActivity extends BaseActivity {
static Button scanlist;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.scan_list);
    List<ScannedProduct> productList = new ArrayList<ScannedProduct>();
    productList = getProductList();
    final ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
    scanlist = (Button) findViewById(R.id.addtowishlist);
    scanlist.setEnabled(false);
    lv.setAdapter(new ProductListAdapter(this, productList, scanlist));
}
```

adapter ;getview

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder;
    final int pos = position;
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.product_list_row, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.text1 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.productid);
        holder.text1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.i("List",""+pos);

            }
        });
        holder.text2 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.price);
        holder.image = (ImageView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.productimageid);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {

        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    holder.text1.setText(productList.get(position).getTitle());
    holder.text2.setText(productList.get(position).getPrice().toString());
    if(productList.get(position).getSmallImage() != null){
    byte [] bb= (productList.get(position).getSmallImage());
    holder.image.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bb, 0, bb.length));
    }
    else{
        holder.image.setImageBitmap(null);
        holder.image.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.highlight_disabled);
    }



//  holder.image.setImageBitmap(Utils.loadBitmap(productList.get(position).getSmallImage()));
    final CheckBox check = (CheckBox) convertView
            .findViewById(R.id.checkbox);
    check.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                boolean isChecked) {
            if (check.isChecked()) {

                ProductListAdapter.count++;
            } else {
                ProductListAdapter.count--;
            }
            if (ProductListAdapter.count == 0) {
                //showOrHideButton.setClickable(false);
                //showOrHideButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                showOrHideButton.setEnabled(false);
            } else {
                //showOrHideButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                showOrHideButton.setEnabled(true);
            }

        }
    });
    return convertView;
}

static class ViewHolder {
    TextView text1;
    ImageView image;
    TextView text2;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 options :

- as you do : define a OnClickListener for each view. But then note that all items could share the same listener (thus declared as a field and not inlined as you did), this would use less memory.
- use a [OnItemClickListener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2965698/listview-setonitemclicklistener-and-setonitemselectedlistener-to-store-the-selec)

The second one is more practical but I remember there is a limitation using it but can't remember what it was. I personnaly use the first strategy.

Comment: if i remember correctly, some focusing issues come into play with a checkbox in a listView. The checkbox steals the focus once selected and prevents the list item from being tapped...

Comment: Is there a way to get the position of the row clicked . My onclick function is :  Intent intent = new Intent(parentActivity,
      SearchResultActivity.class);  so if i define it as a memeber i need a way to get the postion of the row clicked
    intent.putExtra("barcode", productList.get(pos).getBarcode());
    intent.putExtra("format", productList.get(pos).getFormat());
    Log.i("", "" + productList.get(pos).getBarcode());
    parentActivity.startActivity(intent);
    Log.i("", "" + pos);

Comment: so if i define the function as memeber , i need a way to get the  postion for every click

Comment: reformatting my comment : Is there a way to get the position of the row clicked . My onclick function is :        Intent intent = new Intent(parentActivity, SearchResultActivity.class);   intent.putExtra("barcode", productList.get(pos).getBarcode()); intent.putExtra("format", productList.get(pos).getFormat()); Log.i("", "" + productList.get(pos).getBarcode()); parentActivity.startActivity(intent);                    so if i define the function as memeber , i need a way to get the postion for every click

Comment: Either your row view should have the information or use a ItemClickListener for that.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer , in hurry to get things done i didnt mention it :)